# Loop using while True: Python 2

Tags: python, time

I have tried using "while True: to have this program loop without any success.

Trying to have the program loop back to the beginning and just print time on one single line.

The print out in the program gives a blank answer when I use "while True".

```
while True:

import datetime

import pytz

T = datetime.datetime.now()

print(T)
```

Comment: Can you please fix your indentation (using space) (4 spaces in front of code line to make it appear as code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably an indentation problem. In Python indentation is the key to define block:

```
while True:
    import datetime
    import pytz
    T = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(T)
```

Output:

```
...
2017-05-23 11:04:04.209599
2017-05-23 11:04:04.209606
2017-05-23 11:04:04.209613
2017-05-23 11:04:04.209620
2017-05-23 11:04:04.209627
2017-05-23 11:04:04.209634
...
```